# How to One Hot Encode a Dataframe Column in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to convert a column Dataframe with One Hot Encoder with this code.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
df['label'] = OneHotEncoder().fit(df['label']).toarray()
```

This is the traceback

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
  array=['Label1' 'Label1' 'Label1' 'Label1' 'Label1'
 'Label1' 'Label1' 'Label1' 'Label1' 'Label1'
  'Label2' 'Label2' 'Label2' 'Label2' 'Label2' 'Label2' 'Label2'
 'Label2' 'Label2' 'Label2' 'Label3' 'Label3' 'Label3' 'Label3' 'Label3' 'Label3'
 'Label3' 'Label3' 'Label3' 'Label3' 'Label4' 'Label4' 'Label4' 'Label4' 'Label4' 'Label4'
 'Label4' 'Label4' 'Label4' 'Label4' 'Label5' 'Label5' 'Label5'
 'Label5' 'Label5' 'Label5' 'Label5' 'Label5'
 'Label5' 'Label5' 'Label6' 'Label6' 'Label6'
 'Label6' 'Label6' 'Label6' 'Label6' 'Label6'
 'Label6' 'Label6' 'Label7' 'Label7' 'Label7'
 'Label7' 'Label7' 'Label7' 'Label7' 'Label7'
 'Label7' 'Label7' 'Label8' 'Label8' 'Label8' 'Label8' 'Label8'
 'Label8' 'Label8' 'Label8' 'Label8' 'Label8' 'Label9' 'Label9'
 'Label9' 'Label9' 'Label9' 'Label9' 'Label9' 'Label9'
 'Label9' 'Label9' 'Label10' 'Label10' 'Label10' 'Label10' 'Label10'
 'Label10' 'Label10' 'Label10' 'Label10' 'Label10' 'Label11' 'Label11'
 'Label11' 'Label11' 'Label11' 'Label11' 'Label11' 'Label11' 'Label11' 'Label11'
 'Label12' 'Label12' 'Label12' 'Label12' 'Label12' 'Label12'
 'Label12' 'Label12' 'Label12' 'Label12'].
  Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or 
  array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I already tried to reshape but the traceback is that a series has no attribute reshape. What is a workaround to use One Hot Encoder?

Comment: I don't know about `OneHotEncoder` API, but try this: `df = pd.get_dummies(data = df, columns = ['label'])`. This will give you the same result.

Comment: And this is a duplicate question, this type of question is asked on Stack Overflow every week, so check those too.

Comment: I'm sorry that is a duplicate question. I only found solutions with pd.get_dummies, I'd like to know if there are some differencies with One Hot Encoding

Answer (score 1):

See below, but note that you cannot assign the results of the OneHotEncoder to a single data frame column. I suspect that you are looking for the [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) instead.

**OneHotEncoder**

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': ['Label1', 'Label4', 'Label2', 'Label2', 'Label1', 'Label3', 'Label3']
})

X = df['label'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
enc = OneHotEncoder().fit(X)

X = enc.transform(X).toarray()
print(X)
# [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0.]]

X = enc.inverse_transform(X)
print(X)
# [['Label1']
#  ['Label4']
#  ['Label2']
#  ['Label2']
#  ['Label1']
#  ['Label3']
#  ['Label3']]
```

**LabelEncoder**

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'label': ['Label1', 'Label4', 'Label2', 'Label2', 'Label1', 'Label3', 'Label3']
})

y = df['label'].values
enc = LabelEncoder().fit(y)

y = enc.transform(y)
print(y)
# [0 3 1 1 0 2 2]

y = enc.inverse_transform(y)
print(y)
# ['Label1' 'Label4' 'Label2' 'Label2' 'Label1' 'Label3' 'Label3']
```

Comment: While doing enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit(df["sales"]), I am getting error as "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['ab' 'vg' 'ab' 'iu' 'ab' 'vg' 'iu'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific function in pandas for it called `get_dummies` [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

```py
pd.get_dummies(df['Label'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

encoder = OneHotEncoder(drop='first') 
onehot = encoder.fit_transform(df[['label']])
feature_name = encoder.categories_[0]
onehot_df = pd.DataFrame(onehot.toarray(), columns=feature_name[1:])
df_enumeric= pd.concat([df_enumeric, onehot_df], axis=1)
df_X_enumeric.drop('label', axis=1, inplace=True)
```